# Python - specifying file names in for loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I'd like to iterate a python script over a set of data variables. I have input data variables named `data_X`, `data_Y`, etc. which are defined at the beginning of my script, e.g. `data_X = [1, 2, 5, 42, 793]`. In bash, I could just use "$X" to specify that I want the string, so I'm looking for a python equivelent. 
When I try

```
for variable in ['X', 'Y']:
run_data = 'data_' + variable
```

what happens is that run_data is now equal to a string `data_X`, but not equal to the actual data that I had earlier defined as `data_X`

How do I specify that I want `run_data` to equal the values originally assigned to `data_X`?

Comment: ideally something like the equivalent of bash "$X"

Comment: Check the duplicate flag at the top of the page.

Comment: edited to clarify

Comment: In `for variable in ['X', 'Y']:` you are accessing the variables X and Y. You do not have variables named `X` or `Y`. You have variables named `data_X` and `data_Y`. Have you tried using the variables names?

Comment: Later in the script I need to call just 'X' and 'Y' for output, hence not wanting to have a bunch of unnecessary text in the names

Comment: Well if you want to access a variable you have to call it by its name. For example if I create a string called `helloWorld` and assign it as `Hello World! :)` and then I try saying `print(hello)` it will not work cause it is not assigned. In this case, you're looping through the list that contains values X and Y, which makes both your data_X and data_Y variables irrelevant, and you might as well remove them if this is what you wish